# Changing color of YUI pie chart after creation

Tags: javascript, yui, pie-chart

I want to change the array of colors available to a pie-chart after I have created it. I think I need to use the setSeriesStyles method but I cannot find any examples of it and the [documentation](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.Chart.html#method_setSeriesStyles) is not clear.

So far I have tried

```
pieChart.setSeriesStyles([{colors: ['#D4D4D4']}]);
```

and

```
pieChart.setSeriesStyles([{ style: { colors: ['#D4D4D4']}}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I have a live datasource that I am polling, I can listen for an event when the data changes and then update the chart before sending the data onto it.

```
 datasource.doBeforeCallback = function(oRequest, oFullResponse, oParsedResponse, oCallback) {
    if (!oParsedResponse.results || oParsedResponse.results.length < 1) {
        oParsedResponse.results = [{ "name": "No Activity", "count": "0" }];
        mychart._seriesDefs.style.colors = [{style: { colors: ['#000000']}}];
    } else {
        mychart._seriesDefs = null; // sets color array back to default
    }
    return oParsedResponse;
};
```